# Turtlebot Indigo install from source running into Error processing 'yocs_msgs'

Tags: ros, turtlebot, jetson-tk1

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I install turtlebot indigo on jetson tk1 from source and I get this error:

> Exception caught during install: Error processing 'yocs_msgs' : [yocs_msgs] Checkout of https://github.com/yujinrobot/yocs_msgs.git version indigo into /home/ubuntu/kobuki/src/yocs_msgs failed.

> ERROR in config: Error processing 'yocs_msgs' : [yocs_msgs] Checkout of https://github.com/yujinrobot/yocs_msgs.git version indigo into /home/ubuntu/kobuki/src/yocs_msgs failed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249856/turtlebot-indigo-install-from-source-running-into-error-processing-%27yocs_msgs%27/) by [Fighting_bird](https://answers.ros.org/users/26255/fighting_bird/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2016-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Checkout of https://github.com/yujinrobot/yocs_ms... **version indigo** into /home/ubuntu/kobuki/src/yocs_msgs failed.

As you can see from the list of branches over at [yujinrobot/yocs_msgs/branches](https://github.com/yujinrobot/yocs_msgs/branches), there is no `indigo` branch (any more).

I've seen a few of these questions already, it'd probably be a good idea to report this issue over at the [issue tracker](https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki/issues). It would seem the tutorial you followed needs to be updated, or the `.rosinstall` file.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fighting_bird](https://answers.ros.org/users/26255/fighting_bird/) on 2016-12-12**:
Thanks for your answer!